# Using which(), !is.na() and parameter like [1,]

Tags: r

Can someone describe exactly (I understand partially) what the following line does?

```
which(!is.na(table[1,]))
```

1) `table[1,]` = ?  line 1 or column 1 or of a file called "table"?

2) `!is.na` = why the `!`?  (`is.na` is used to eliminate the `NA` but why the `!`?  Normally, `!` represents negative (not equal).

Comment: What is `table` ?  Is it a `matrix`, `data.frame` or `table` object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1686/basic-subsetting#t=201701201802397934012

Comment: this is dataset, result of set (rbind) of few other dataset

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, now I understand!

Comment: `is.na` is used to **find** NA values, not eliminate them.  Next, think of `!` as the opposite, when used on a logical vector.  All this is explained in the help files, btw.

Answer (score 1):

If we split the function to pieces,

```
table[1,]
```

subset the first row of the dataset

```
is.na(table[1,])
```

checks whether there are NA values in the first row.  It will return a vector of logical elements (TRUE for NA and FALSE for non-NA).

`!` is negation operator.  So, it will convert the TRUE to FALSE and vice versa to give a vector of logical elements that are non NA for TRUE values

```
!is.na(table[1,])
```

and lastly the `which` wrapper gives the numeric index of TRUE values

---

To demonstrate an example, say we have a `matrix`

```
 m1 <- matrix(c(NA, 0, 1, 2), 2, 2)
```

Then, if we follow the steps

```
m1[1,] #returns the 1st row as a vector
#[1] NA  1

is.na(m1[1,]) #returns TRUE for NA
#[1]  TRUE FALSE

!is.na(m1[1,]) #returns TRUE for non-NA elements
#[1] FALSE  TRUE

which(!is.na(m1[1,]))
#[1] 2

#or perhaps more usefully
which(is.na(m1[1,]))
#[1] 1
```